# How to set inline check box in a bootstrap panel header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, panel

How can I set this bootstrap check box to be in the same line as the panel heading?

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">some heading
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> check me
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>       
<div class="panel-body">
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Rr7qf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rnirnber mentioned, a `div` is ablock element by default. You can override this behaviour. This should do the trick:

```
<div class="checkbox" style="display: inline">
```

update:

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
   <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading
      <div class="checkbox" style="display:inline">
         <label>
             <input type="checkbox" style="float:inherit;"/>check box
         </label>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>       
<div class="panel-body">
</div>
```

Comment: Look at the fiddle, it's just bootstrap css

Comment: I saw it. If you remove the CSS and add the style from above, the inline is correct. There seems to be padding/margin/absolute position or somthing - no idea, but it is causing the problem.

Comment: See my update above. Just override the bootstrap CSS. Use The developer tools of your browser (F12) for fine tuning.

Comment: I just found out that i can also use the bootstrap class "checkbox-inline" which does the trick. But your solution works nicely as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your checkbox is on a new line because it's wrapped in it's own `<div>` tag.
By convention, `<div>` elements have a default display: block property.

Block elements go on their own line, end of story.
You should look into floats or possibly (even more easily) just getting rid of the unnecessary div.